# Is storing an uploaded file into a variable name safe?

Tags: php

I have a form in which a file is uploaded. I'm currently trying to turn the written code into a function that accepts a file as a parameter and then does a variety of tasks. I check the file size, check if the file extension/mime type is allowed (from two arrays of allowed types/mime types), and then use the move_uploaded_file function to move it to an appropriate directory.

I was thinking of using this to put the file into the parameter of the function:

```
fileHandling($_FILES["file_name"]) {
  // do stuff;
}
```

However is this actually retrieving the data from the form or would I have to use the $_POST method? The function doesn't really return anything, its just a do-all function that just handles the file.

Comment: 1) The code snippet you show is invalid nonsense. 2) Just storing a name, or *any* value, in a variable will do absolutely nothing you need to be afraid of. Security only starts playing a role when you use this value in something that *does* something; e.g. writing it to the file system, interpolate it into a database query etc.

Comment: The 'invalid nonsense' was me trying to pass a certain file into a function. I didn't know how to do it. Thank you, I wasn't sure if it was secure to store it in a variable or something. I'll implement the security features/checks when I start saving the file under a directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files uploaded with a form are placed in the `$_FILES` global.

Best practice is to store your files [below the web root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7701799/shared-hosting-how-to-php-include-file-below-web-root) to prevent direct linking.   You'd need to ensure you have a folder created below your web root, and that your [php.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php) file has this path as [set_include_path](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php).

Comment: Oh, I see. So if I were to pass this, I would just pass the $_FILES global with the filename at hand? So $_FILES["file_name"].

Comment: `$_FILES` is an array with the file data.  Please see updated answer for additional safety tip.

Comment: Thank you for the safety suggestion. I'll have to research it some more because I'm running a localhost server using WAMP.

Comment: If your app is accessible/usable by others, and especially if it is publicly available, be sure to check out `set_include_path` and store files in a folder there.  If you include a folder you can create subfolders without needing to explicitly set them in the `php.ini`.  Just set the top level folder and you're good to go.

Comment: It will be publicly available soon. Thanks, I'll make sure to implement it!